# How to to detect mobile keyboard enter/submit with react material TextField

Tags: material-ui, react-dom

I am coding in react dom/web

```
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.9.2",
```

This is my code a simple text box

```
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
...
...
<TextField
    onSubmitEditing={onSubmitEditing}
```

I am assuming `onSubmitEditing` will be there similar to react native, But I am getting an error

```
Warning: Unknown event handler property `onSubmitEditing`. It will be ignored.
```

pressing enter key browser/mobile emulator does nothing

Comment: use onKeyDown, then check keyCode from event to see if it is the enter key.

Comment: thanks, `keyCode` is deprecated, I used `onKeyPress` and `event.key === 'Enter'` with `preventDefault()` in case if there is a `<form` tag